# MySQL Query that works on server doesn't work locally

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I took a website which is currently live and transferred everything to my computer so I can work on it locally. I am in the process of getting everything working locally but can't get my MySQL queries to work. I am connected to a database which is identical to the original database that the website was running on.

The error I'm getting is:
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
(yes I am going to move everything to mysqli once I get this working)

I've tested very simple queries and had no luck. Here is one I tried:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', null, 'database_name') or die("Could not connect.");
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `data` FROM `test-table` WHERE `id` = 0"), 0);
?>
```

Does this have something to do with the fact that I am running locally?

I'm running this on WAMP, Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) PHP/5.4.3

Comment: Are you sure that your local MySQL server has a `root` user with no password?

Comment: The boolean is probably `false` from a failure somewhere in the middle of your call chain on the second line. Try splitting out each call individually and testing for individual errors.

Comment: Your 4th parameter in `mysql_connect()` is wrong, it should be Boolean. However, it would be correct if you were using the MySQLi extension instead.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not selecting the database. As mentioned above 4th parameter is wrong. You have to call mysql_select_db after you established the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_select_db('database_name')` instead of incorrectly passing the database name to the mysql_connect function.

See the manuals:

- [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
- [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

If I were in the process of updating from mysql_* to mysqli_* I would first change my functions then debug as it will save from doing debugging only to change it and debug again. Just a thought...